# is there any audio video player for web page

Tags: flash, video-conversion

I am creating a website where user can upload video's audio's in different formats but i want a single flash player (or any other player) which open on my web page and plays the respective video or audio.

I have searched a lot on google but could not found any.

Also i dont want to convert the videos on upload because it is too costly in terms of usage of memory and CPU. (i checked for converting 4 video's it took around 70% of CPU and 25 sec. to convert all)

Is there any such player which is used on webpage to play video's/audio's of all formats.

Can we create any such kind of flash player? If yes where shall i start from?

I have got some details here http://activeden.net/category/flash/video-players/video-players.

Can anyone guide me here for the demo or example to see if the above player plays the multiple format players properly, on a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to study, then go through open source project:
[Miro](http://www.getmiro.com/)

There are many free players for web page.

Go through this links having audio / video players:

1. http://www.instantshift.com/2010/05/14/21-free-video-players-for-your-website-and-blogs/
2. http://www.instantshift.com/2010/02/10/21-free-music-players-for-your-website/
3. http://www.webdesignbooth.com/10-easy-to-implement-flash-based-mp3-players-for-your-website/
4. http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2009/05/13-essential-flash-video-and-audio-players-for-your-website-or-blog.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this open source project: [flowplayer.org](http://flowplayer.org)

It is highly customizable and is able to add audio player:

http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/audio.html#example-flowplayer-as-a-music-box

Comment: hey can you tell me which formats (extensions) of audio and video are supported by this player?

Comment: There is a limit to what Flash itself supports (as far as I know of). You can have a look at flowplayers supported formats [here](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/technical-facts.html#formats).
The best idea would be to convert them to flv in my opinion (like YouTube). Flv is just a container file format. That way you are consistent.

Comment: Another possibility is [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/). This support more file formats because it uses the capability of HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

For .flv, .mp4, and .mp3, [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/) or [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/) will work fine.  For the other formats, there are a few possibilities, but none of them are as reliable as the above players.  For those less suitable file formats, I suggest setting up [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to automatically convert your files to one of the preferred file formats.  You should be able to do that in the server-side code for your upload page.

For reference, the options that I know of for embedding those odd file formats in webpages are embedding Windows Media Player (IE-only), using JWPlayer's Silverlight video player (only works for .wmv and .wma, and only for people with Silverlight), and just linking to the file in the webpage with an `<object>` or `<a>` tag (tends to work well with .wav, may work for some people with the other formats - very dependent on what programs are installed on the computer).  JWPlayer (due to its HTML5 mode) also has a chance of being able to play odd file formats for some people, mostly depending on their browser.